# Not able to Validate Azure b2c generated JWT tokken

Tags: c#, azure, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-webapi, azure-ad-b2c

Hi I am using Azure B2c Service for authentication in asp.net core MVC Application, after the Authentication, I am using following code

```
string token = await HttpContext.GetTokenAsync("id_token");
```

to get the Token so I can call another asp.net core API to get the data, but whenever I tried to call the API using token I am getting the following error in postman.

> `AuthenticationFailed: IDX10501: Signature validation failed. Unable to match keys: 
>   kid: 'piVlloQDSMKxh1m2ygqGSVdgFpA',`

Comment: What is the authority? Do you use correct metadata endpoint? It's something like https://login.microsoftonline.com/tfp/{0}/{1}/v2.0/.well-known/openid-configuration. See this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43276977/azure-ad-b2c-error-idx10501-signature-validation-failed.

Comment: i am using default configuration of Azure ad for login but on API i configure OWIN middleware for authentication

Comment: i want to call my asp.net core web api's from asp.net core web Application but i am not able to generate proper jwt token for communication